# Oneboxing a onebox from a different chat server generates a weird URL

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, onebox

So if you try to onebox a onebox from a different chat server, [this weirdness happens](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2365123#2365123). Basically, it generates this URL:

> https://chat.stackexchange.com//stackoverflow.com/questions/25609915/php-sql-match-against

Now, obviously that isn't right. I've also tested this [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17450510#17450510), and I'm assuming it's broken on chat.SO too. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be fixed up now. We were a wee bit overzealous and didn't check for the links that started with `/`, but were already protocol-relative rather than site-relative.

Comment: Lovely. Indeed, it is fixed. :)

Answer (score 8):

Damnit, [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9) knows my weak spot. I wrote a [quick 'n dirty userscript](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/raw/master/stack-utilities-onebox-link-hack.user.js) ([source](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/blob/master/stack-utilities-onebox-link-hack.user.js)) to patch this until it's fixed properly.

Tested in Chrome on the example in the question and the one that prompted the bounty, but it should work in Firefox too.

Comment: Well, you're being paid well for this! :-)

Answer (score 7):

Downside of the script from Tim is that when hovering over the link the broken link is shown. My script fixes the DOM.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Fix broken double links
// @namespace    http://stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  fix one-one-boxes
// @author       rene
// @match        *://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {

    // fix the link in the one box
    function fixup(item) {
        var a = $(item),
            hrefs = a.prop('href').split('//');
        if (hrefs.length > 2) {
            hrefs.shift();
            hrefs.shift();
            a.prop('href', '//' + hrefs.join('//'));
        }
    }

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            var i,
                box;
            for(i=0; i< mutation.addedNodes.length; i = i + 1) {
                box = $(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
                console.log(box);
                box.find('div.ob-post-title a').each(function () {
                    fixup(this);
                });
            }
        });    
    });

    // chat window
    if ($('div#chat').length >0) {
        console.log('obs');
        observer.observe($('div#chat')[0], {childList:true, subtree: true});
    }

    //transcript
    $('div.ob-post-title a').each(function () {
        fixup(this);
    });
}())
```

Comment: I like both of these scripts, but I like Tim's more because it's simpler and doesn't bother replacing the URL until I click. OTOH, this uses jQuery... Decisions, decisions...

Comment: Thanks @Shog9 much appreciated.